# Execute Python Script on Motion Eye on event of Motion Detection

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have installed motioneye on a raspberry pi and it's working perfectly (images and videos are recording which I can access through FTP). Motion detection is enabled with a mask.

I have written a .py script that will open a new web browser displaying the streamed video so colleagues around the office can see at a glance who has entered the building (the script works perfectly when exectued in PyCharm)

I have placed the executbale .py file in /home/data/browse.py

[image]

However, it doesn't seem to execute when motion has been detected and captured/recorded.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: [run a python script in terminal without the python command](//stackoverflow.com/a/15587911) You can probably ignore the 3rd part.

Comment: I already a shebang at the start of the script.